# Galaxy s4 green surfaceView error/bug

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

In my app I'm using surface view, on Galaxy S3 it works fine also on LG G2, I bought the S4 for testing my app and I get this really weird problem, the Surface View is partly green and the area that left without green is divided to 3 Surface Views.

Here is a photo 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGVh2.png

Comment: That particular shade of green looks like a zeroed-out YUV buffer (if it were RGB, it'd be black).  So maybe there's no data from the camera?

Comment: it does getting data from the camera, look at the image that I have posted and you'll see on the right side 3 images, actually these 3 "images" are 3 fully working previews, the only thing that I don't get that what could cause the View to look like it while on other 2 devices that I have tested it on (SGS3, LG G2), it works fine.

Comment: Ive found the problem, it was the setPreviewSize that caused it, I gave it wrong values.. So by deleting that line the problem was solved :)